# Remove objects from array of objects swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, object

I have an issue and need your help.
I have array of objects

```
var arrayDirection: [Directions]
```

every object has properties:

```
var name: String?
var uniqueId: Int?
```

I need find and leave only one object whose values of properties duplicate values of properties of another objects from that array.

For example I print in console:

```
for object in arrayDirection {
    print(object.name, object.uniqueId)
}
```

and see:

> Optional("name1") Optional(833)
>
> Optional("name1") Optional(833)
>
> Optional("name2") Optional(833)
>
> Optional("name4") Optional(833)
>
> Optional("name1") Optional(833)
>
> Optional("name1") Optional(862)

So, I need remove `Optional("name1") Optional(833)` because there are 3 in array and leave only one as result I'd like to see:

> Optional("name1") Optional(833)
>
> Optional("name2") Optional(833)
>
> Optional("name3") Optional(833)
>
> Optional("name1") Optional(862)

Comment: There are several similar Q&As already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709066/remove-duplicate-objects-in-an-array, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304150/remove-duplicated-in-a-struct-array, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/does-there-exist-within-swifts-api-an-easy-way-to-remove-duplicate-elements-fro

Comment: I saw it, but I need compare two different properties

Comment: Here is another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153674/remove-duplicate-structs-in-array-based-on-struct-property-in-swift – All the solutions can be used for types with arbitrary many properties.

Comment: @MartinR great! It's working as must, thank you for the last link

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to remove duplicate from your data set. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34709118/3172726) will help what you want to achieve.

However in short, use **Set** to avoid duplicate data.

Comment: yes, I understand, but how to do it for several properties?

Comment: if this answer is helpful, hope you accept it too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could `reduce` the array:

```
let reducedArray: [Direction] = myArray.reduce([]) { result, direction in
   result.contains(where: { $0.uniqueId == direction.uniqueId }) ? result : result + [direction]
}
```

Obviously this piece of code assumes that you only want to check if the IDs duplicate, if you want to check whether whole objects duplicate you could either implement the `Equatable` protocol for your `Directions` type, or do it like that:

```
let reducedArray: [Direction] = myArray.reduce([]) { result, direction in
   result.contains(where: { $0.uniqueId == direction.uniqueId && $0.name == direction.name }) ? result : result + [direction]
}
```

And with `Equatable` protocol implemented it gets actually really simple:

```
let reducedArray: [Direction] = myArray.reduce([]) { result, direction in
   result.contains(where: { $0 == direction }) ? result : result + [direction]
}
```