# Swift: Merge custom object elements of an Array if they have the same key

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a Realm Object class called `Performance` which looks like this

```
class Performance: Object {

@objc dynamic var move = ""
@objc dynamic var score = 0

}
```

and when I print the results of the Realm object I get something like this

```
 [Performance {
  move = Run;
  score = 3;
}, Performance {
  move = Walk;
  score = 3;
}, Performance {
  move = Run;
  score = 2;
}]
```

Then I try to convert the realm results into an Array so that I can merge the performances with the same move and add their score so that I can show the user which of their move has the highest and lowest scores.

I would want to know if there is any chance where I can merge the `Performance` with the same move and add their score so that the array would look like this.

```
[Performance {
move = Run;
score = 5;
}, Performance {
move = Walk;
score = 3;
}]
```

I have tried few solutions like  [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153674/remove-duplicate-structs-in-array-based-on-struct-property-in-swift), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/removing-duplicate-elements-from-an-array) and [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307188/removing-duplicates-from-array-of-custom-objects-swift).

But they are not really helpful for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through the array and create a dictionary with your move type being the key.

For example:

```
var totals: [MoveType: Int] = [:]
for item in performances {
    totals[item.move] = item.score + (totals[item.move] ?? 0)
}
```

For each item, this will add the score to the dictionary for the relevant move type, creating a new dictionary entry if it's the first item with that move type.

Comment: Just use `Dictionary(groupingBy:)`.